# Loss of precision of a long number elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch, long-integer

I have a set of documents within my index in which I have an "id" field which during automatic insertion was mapped to type "long". The problem is that when I go to view the documents in JSON format, or export them from ES with elasticdump the value of that field loses precision. I have tried reindexing that field to type "text" but unfortunately it is assigned the truncated value and not the correct one. So what happens is that if the field "id" I want it to have as its value 1063070759378190336 (a value that I display correctly from the ES dashboard) as a result of the reindex or when displaying in json format the field "id" has the truncated value 1063070759378190300. Need a solution to figure out how to maintain the correct value without it being truncated on export and during display in JSON format. Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by "ES dashboard"? where are you displaying them as json?

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke by Dashboard I meant the data view section of the index: here when I go to view the individual document the "id" field in question has the correct value, while when I go to click on the JSON format view it loses precision.

Comment: you mean kibana discover?